# Analyzing Simple Bubble Sort Loop (Worst Case)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm given a simple pseoducode algorithm:

```
for j=1 to A.length-1 //first line 
  for i =1 to A.length-j //second line 
    if A[i-1] >A[i]
      swap A[i-1] and A[i]
```

I'm told that the second line runs as such (WORST CASE:

```
n+(n-1)+...+2 = n(n+1)/2-1
```

I understand that when the first line runs, the second loop runs n times, each next iteration of j, the second loop runs 1 less times `(n-1) +(n-2)` etc.
I understand that it's clearly a summation, here but what I don't get is why the last thing added is `2` (FOR THE SECOND LINE).

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering A.length to be n, you could clearly verify the same. I am doing it for you :

```
for j=1 to n-1 //first line 
  for i =1 to n-j //second line 
    if A[i-1] >A[i]
     swap A[i-1] and A[i]
```

So, for the first iteration of outer loop at j = 1, inner loop runs from 1 to n-1 times. => n-1

For second iteration of outer loop, inner loop runs from 1 to n-2 times. => n-2

For ith iteration of outer loop, the inner loop will run for 1 to n-i times, => n-i .

Last iteration of outer loop will be when j = n-1, the inner loop will run for i = 1 to n-(n - 1) = 1 time.

So, result will be summation of n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1 = (n-1)*n/2.

SO, it should be obviously 1 at the end.

> I understand that it's clearly a summation, here but what I don't get
>   is why the last thing added is 2 (FOR THE SECOND LINE).

I suggest you to talk with your friend/professor over this, who has, obviously, incorrectly informed you. It is what I have solved here.

People generally think that when the array's top n-1 elements have been sorted, the last one would already fit the exact place. So, they generally presume this and leave the last step.

But, in computation OR algorithm, we (generally) compute this. Your this code is computing that here.

Comment: Is their a difference between how many times a line runs and executes? I learned in class that the first line runs/executes n times, not n-1. But in another class, I learned it the otherway around.. I don't even know anymore.

Comment: Read my comment, it's the actual solution from my professor, not a freind. This is how we learned it.

Comment: When you count from 1,2,3,...,n, then actual running is for n+1 times, that is running of loop testing statement is considered, which results in addition of 1 even in the case of false. But, people generally care only about the successful execution of inner body, not the testing statement. You should stick with this one, as even CLRS has later mentioned this line. Though, if being more specific, you should add +1 in all cases where you need exact calculation. It is OK for just worst-case analysis.

Comment: I wish this would have been clarified in class, thanks.

Comment: @user3739406 - You are most welcome in asking any doubts over here.